# In fine-uploader is there a callback for the json resturned by the server?

Tags: fine-uploader

By default fine-uploader marks an upload as a success when it recieves the following json file.

```
{ "success": "true" }
```

Does fine-uploader support passing extra data back to the client and doing something with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All data passed from your server can be accessed on the 3rd parameter passed to your [`onComplete` event handler](https://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/events.html#complete), which is a JavaScript object. Note that the `XMLHttpRequest instance used to send the request is also available as the 4th param.